# Redshift - Cross account cluster sync-up

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I need to sync up data from one Redshift cluster to another account's redshift cluster including Accesses. I have TBs of data spanned across multiple tables. I need to do this sync-up everyday.

Below two options seems to have some demerits:

1. UNLOAD and LOAD will work table by table would not suffix this need.
2. Restore through cluster snapshot will create a brand new cluster which will change the end point.

Is there any other option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **no provided "sync" capability between Redshift clusters**. You might be able to use a third-party utility that can sync the data, but those utilities would also use `UNLOAD` and `COPY` on a table-by-table basis.

If your concern is that the cluster endpoint changes, then you could **use Amazon Route 53 to define your own DNS name**. Then, when the cluster is restored, simply update the `CNAME` record in Route 53 to point to the new endpoint DNS name. This way, the same DNS name can be used even when the endpoint changes.

Comment: Thanks John. I am trying that out. Just a quick question on restoring through snapshot. Will fine-grain access(tables, views, functions) be preserved after restore to new cluster?

Comment: Yes, the cluster will be identical except for the name.

Comment: Thanks John, this helps.